# displaying person class data in text boxes C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

]I need to write a mini program in C# using windows forms - I am new to C# and programming, so bare over with me.
lets say I have 10 doctors (laege) and I want to display each doctors information such as CVR number, address, email and so on - many different valules (bool, int, strings)
I have created a class called praksisOplysninger (information of the doctors)
added one doctor (laege1) in my button handler.
How can i display the data, when the user enters yderNr - then the rest of the information need to be displayed - I have made several textboxes for this.
Now I am getting an error called to many recursion - i need to stop my loop inside my class of doctors - i have tried for several hours - please help
thanx in advance :)

> Blockquote

**this is my class of doctors - I have laege1-10 in my class **
laege is equal to a doctor in Denmark ;) Now I get a recursion error.. how can I stop the loop? There is no error in the code in the button handler.

```
`laegeInfo laege1 = new laegeInfo()
    {
        yderNr = 012345,
        navn = "Johannes Andersen",
        CVR = 4100,
        adresse = "Frederiksvej 15, Faxe",
        telefon = 32424323,
        email = "JAplo@.dgm",
        kommune = 4640,
        solo = true,
        flermands = false,
        besoeg = 20,
        FMKBesoeg = true,
        sidsteBesoeg = new DateTime(2016, 6, 3)
```

`{

> Blockquote

```
      var  userInput = int.Parse(txtPraksisoplysningerYderNr.Text);
        var laege = laeger.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Ydernr == userInput);
        if(laege != null)
        {
            txtLaegensNavn.Text = laege.Navn;
            txtCVR.Text = laege.Cvr.ToString();
            txtLaegensAdresse.Text = laege.Adresse;
            txtlaegenstlfNR.Text = laege.Telefon.ToString();
            txtLaegensEmail.Text = laege.Email;
            txtLaegensKommune.Text = laege.Kommune.ToString();

        }

        btnFindLaegeOplysning.Show();
```

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: This is on of my doctors:
laegeInfo laege10 = new laegeInfo(10234, "Bent Justesten", 9909, "Asgers park 76, Solrød ",341122, "BJplo@.dgm", 2680, true, false, 4, false, new DateTime(2010, 5, 9));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some list of doctors stored somewhere (database, static list within the doctor class itself, etc.), you may use LINQ to retrieve a specific doctor object in which it's yderNr property equals to the one entered by the user. **For example:**

```
public class Doctor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int YderNr { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doctors = new List<Doctor>
        {
            new Doctor()
            {
                Name = "Jens Andersen",
                PhoneNumber = 12345567,
                YderNr = 02131
            }
        };

        var userInput = int.Parse(txtPraksisoplysningerYderNr.Text);

        var doctor = doctors.SingleOrDefault(d => d.YderNr == userInput);

        if (doctor != null)
        {
            // Set the textbox text with the doctor's data
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on LINQ's `SingleOrDefault()` method, [click here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/singleordefault).

**Update:**

I'm not sure what your textbox names are, but here's how you'd set the textbox's text to the doctor's data within the if statement from the code snippet above:

```
if (doctor != null)
{
    // Set the textbox text with the doctor's data
    txtDoctorName.Text = doctor.Name;
    txtDoctorPhoneNumber.Text = doctor.PhoneNumber;
    txtDoctorYderNr.Text = doctor.YderNr;
}
```

This would work if you have a three textbox controls with the following names: `txtDoctorName`, `txtDoctorPhoneNumber`, and `txtDoctorYderNr`.

Comment: And how can I display the adress info, email info etc. to the given texboxes? Is it necessary to write something like this: txtemail.text(show) for  all boxes ?

Comment: @JeanetteJ.Andersen You'll have to set each individual textbox's text manually. See the **Update** section in my original post.

Comment: thanx you so much, now i need to make a list within  my class containing all the 10 doctors :)

Comment: @JeanetteJ.Andersen No problem, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @JeanetteJ.Andersen Can you update your original post with your new code please? Thanks!

Comment: Hi bryan - how can I get it to work with my list of ten doctors ?

Comment: @JeanetteJ.Andersen What issue are you having exactly? I can't help without seeing more code, since I have no clue what `laeger` is.

Comment: I have updated my post with some more code - recursion error in my class  of doctors ( laeger )

Comment: I have figured it out - thanx for the Help Bryan :) - you really helped me a lot
i changed my doctors from within the class to the form designer... it helped. though I would have guessed a class is better to work with?
and made a foreach loop :)

Answer (score 0):

```
           `laegeInfo laege9 = new laegeInfo()` 
        {
            yderNr = 09123,
            navn = "Mille Andersen",
            CVR = 05232,
            adresse = "Parkvej 90, Sorø",
            telefon = 22996124,
            email = "MAplo@.dgm",
            kommune = 4180,

        };
        laegeInfo laege10 = new laegeInfo()
        {

            yderNr = 10102,
            navn = "Bent Justesen",
            CVR = 00632,
            adresse = "Asgers park 76, Solrød",
            telefon = 99885034,
            email = "BJplo@.dgm",
            kommune = 2680,

        };
        List<laegeInfo> laegers = new List<laegeInfo>(10);
            laegers.Add(laege1);
            laegers.Add(laege2);
            laegers.Add(laege3);
            laegers.Add(laege4);
            laegers.Add(laege5);
            laegers.Add(laege6);
            laegers.Add(laege7);
            laegers.Add(laege8);
            laegers.Add(laege9);
            laegers.Add(laege10);

            var UserInput = int.Parse(txtPraksisoplysningerYderNr.Text);
            var laege = laegers.SingleOrDefault(L => L.yderNr == UserInput);
            if (laege != null)

                foreach (laegeInfo L in laegers)
            {
                txtLaegensNavn.Text = L.navn;

                txtCVR.Text = L.CVR.ToString();

                txtLaegensAdresse.Text = L.adresse;

                txtlaegenstlfNR.Text = L.telefon.ToString();

                txtLaegensEmail.Text = L.email;

                txtLaegensKommune.Text = L.kommune.ToString();
```